# when i create a modal and its overlay, the overlay doesn extend across the document

Tags: asp.net, html, css, modal-dialog

So, with that said, essentially, the case that always comes up.

-modal and overlay appears,

-user scrolls down

-user can click stuff under the overlay

How do i fix that?  Right now, the main issue is with the overlay.

Its CSS is as follows:

```
 .overlay
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        display: none;
        z-index: 7000;
    }
```

Since i am using it in a asp page, the depth of the html is like as follows:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div class = "overlay"></div>
      <div class = "modal">...</div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I wasnt sure if that meant anything.

**Either we can arrange it so that it can stretch the height/width of the overlay or we can make it so the overlay and modal move when you scroll.  I just dont know how to do them**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as your overlay:

```
.overlay {
        background: transparent url(overlay.png) repeat top left;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        z-index: 100;
    }
```

And this is overlay.png: (right click and save as)
[image: And this can be your image that is referenced in the background above.]

This is the markup for the overlay:

```
<div class="overlay" id="overlay1" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Comment: I am not too keen on this being a way to effeciently do it, as to me pure CSS would be more ideal then loading an image over and over, but at least for an initial release this is more then enough